# NonSerialized dind't work

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

i'm serialization a class but i can't exclude some field in my class.

```
[Serializable]
public class DicData
{

    private GDicJson DeserializedGDicJson = new GDicJson();
    public UOCDicData BuiltDicData;                        

    [NonSerialized]
    public string CacheName = "";                          


}
```

in my expection, a public field CacheName didn't include in my *.xml deserialized output, but it included in .xml file.

here are serializing rutine.

```
XmlSerializer myXml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DicData), "test");
myXml.Serialize(myFile, this); //note:a serializing perform in method of himself.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For `XmlSerializer` you want

```
[XmlIgnore]
```

Also, note that the `[Serializable]` is unnecessary in this case.

As a final note: public fields are not encouraged; properties are almos always preferred. The addition of `{get;set;}` would go a long way...

Comment: Marc is right. The XmlSerializer doesn't care about the `[Serializable]` or `[NonSerialized]` attributes.